# Remove a hold from a question

Tags: discussion, scope, closed-questions

How do you remove a hold from a question that has been edited? Who removes the hold? The user?  I posted a question is was put on hold I have since edited to remove the "opinion" nature of the question.

Comment: I am trying to learn

Comment: If it is your own question you click the 'reopen' button and it will be placed in the review queue.  It could take 1/2 day or a full day depending upon when you do it.  The higher ups can also refuse to reopen.  Put the link to your question in the META question

Comment: You can also always flag a question for moderator attention. A moderator's vote is binding and if the question really improved a fits to the standards of TSE, the moderator can reopen the question immediately.

Comment: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/50869/full-moon-party-haad-rin

Comment: thanks for the help guys and or gals

Comment: @GayotFow I do not see a reopen button?

Comment: @Ary_Vandelay17, it might be a hurdle thing.  I put your question into the review queue for reopening.  Based upon what I saw, I do not think it will be successful, but at least people will be able to revive it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing "on hold" status (or "closed" status) is called getting a question reopened, and it works the same way as getting a question put on hold in the first place. Either five community members or one elected moderator must vote to reopen.

Usually, all you should have to do to get a question reopened is edit it to fix whatever problem(s) got it put on hold in the first place.

For more information, see [the community-maintained FAQ entry on closed posts on the network meta site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10583/).